# how to test conditional if with jasmine and angular

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine

i have a problem with testing jasmine, i cant test conditional if. when i run in sonarqube, just that conditional cant detect.

this is my code:

```
login() {
    this.submitted = true;
    this.isLoading = true;

        if (this.loginForm.valid) {
          this.authenticationService
            .login(this.f.username.value, this.f.password.value)
            .pipe(finalize(() => {
              this.loginForm.markAsPristine();
              this.isLoading = false;
            }))
            .subscribe(credentials => {
              this.router.navigate(['/'], { replaceUrl: true });
            }, error => {
              this.error = error;
            });
          this.isLoading = false;
        }
      }
```

this is my testing code:

```
test('testing conditional if', () => {
    component.loginForm.controls['username'].setValue('admin');
    component.loginForm.controls['password'].setValue('12345678');
    expect(component.loginForm.valid).toBeTruthy();
    spyOn(authenticationService, 'login').and
      .returnValue(component.loginForm.markAsPristine());
    expect(component.login().loginForm.isLoading).toBeFalsy();
    component.login();
  });
```

help me guys to solve my problem, i search in every website but cant solve this problem. thank you for your attention and your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Think the issue is `spyOn(authenticationService, 'login').and
      .returnValue(component.loginForm.markAsPristine());` If you spy on it and return a value, you are effectively mocking it. Hence the function will be stubbed and will just return the result of `component.loginForm.markAsPristine()`
From the [jasmine docs](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html):

> Jasmine has test double functions called spies. A spy can stub any function and tracks calls to it and all arguments.

As you want the function to executed for `SonarCube`, but still spy for the purpose of tracking calls, you should be using `callThrough`

`spyOn(authenticationService, 'login').and.callThrough();`
From Docs:

> By chaining the spy with and.callThrough, the spy will still track all calls to it but in addition it will delegate to the actual implementation.

Now this should register with the sonar cube as the code will be executed and if you set `this.loginForm.valid` to `true`, the `if` will execute, and when set to false, the `else` part of the block will execute